Install Bootstrap on Symfony 7, Error message after "package.json" add, and command "npm start"
Error message screencapture
Good morning,
I am installing Boostrap v 5.3.3 in Symfony following the Bootstrap documentation. But I encounter an error when launching the "npm start" command (just after modifying the 'package.json' file with the script provided by the doc on this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/webpack/#import-bootstrap).
I have the:

start
webpack serve

Which is displayed, but which is followed by the error message:
"[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

options has an unknown property '_assetEmittingPreviousFiles'. These properties are valid:
object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, ipc?, liveReload?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }"

Can you help me get out of this blockage please?
thank you
I haven't done anything, I prefer to wait for your suggestions before breaking everything

My "package.json" content
Screencapture of package.json

I found the solution and share it with you, maybe it will be useful to someone else.
The problem was with the content of the "webpack.conf.js" and "package.json" files.
You will find the contents of these two files which worked for me.
Fchier webpack.config.js
Fichier package.json
Enjoy !
